# Where to place a @since tag in a kotlin file without a class?

Tags: kotlin

We usually place the `@author` and `@since` tag in the `javadoc/kdoc` annotation for the top-level class.

But if a `kotlin` file doesn't have any class or object, instead top-level functions, are there any good position to place an `@author` and a `@since` tag?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html), you can place them on elements on top-level functions.  However, if you want to document modules/packages, you'd need to create a separate markdown file.  Refer to the last section of the linked documentation page.